# Getting vertices where google vision API found words

Tags: python, vision

I'm working with the Google Vision API.

I would like to get the vertices ((x,y) locations) of the rectangles where google vision found a block of words. So far I'm getting the text from the google client.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/api-key.json")
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=credentials)

#open file
with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

#call api
image = types.Image(content=content)
response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
document = response.full_text_annotation
```

What I would like is to get the vertices for each block of words in `document.text`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Google has updated the documentation, although it is not so easy to find.

See tutorial on the Google Vision API [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-vision-api-python#7)

The vertices can be found in `response.text_annotations`

Answer (score -1):

From google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/fulltext-annotations), you can find how the API response is structured (BLOCK, PARAGRAPH, ...) and how to retrieve corresponding vertices.

Particularly this function:

```
def get_document_bounds(image_file, feature):
"""Returns document bounds given an image."""
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

bounds = []

with io.open(image_file, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)

response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
document = response.full_text_annotation

# Collect specified feature bounds by enumerating all document features
for page in document.pages:
    for block in page.blocks:
        for paragraph in block.paragraphs:
            for word in paragraph.words:
                for symbol in word.symbols:
                    if (feature == FeatureType.SYMBOL):
                        bounds.append(symbol.bounding_box)

                if (feature == FeatureType.WORD):
                    bounds.append(word.bounding_box)

            if (feature == FeatureType.PARA):
                bounds.append(paragraph.bounding_box)

        if (feature == FeatureType.BLOCK):
            bounds.append(block.bounding_box)

    if (feature == FeatureType.PAGE):
        bounds.append(block.bounding_box)

# The list `bounds` contains the coordinates of the bounding boxes.
return bounds
```